# Redirect 301 in .htaccess causes 500 server error (Redirect to non-URL)

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

have such kind of error.

When adding `Redirect 301` rule to `.htaccess` file like:

```
Redirect 301 "/page1.html" "/dir1/"
```

My site fails with 500 server error and in apache error log this error appears:

```
[Wed Mar 16 11:08:52 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /home/htdocs/site.com/www/.htaccess: Redirect to non-URL
```

*Mod rewrite is installed, also tried to provide urls without quotes.*

*On production server this .htaccess works fine, but on local causes troubles*

Any ideas, please)

---

This rule works

```
Redirect 301 "/page1.html" "http://www.site.com/dir1/"
```

but I need a way to supply relative paths instead of full urls (production server works that  way)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changed all `Redirect 301` rules to:

```
RewriteRule ^/page1.html$ /dir1/page.html [R=301,L]
```

now working. But how does it work on production?

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had the exact same issue. Adding "http://domain.com" in front of "/mypage" worked; I am still testing to get it to work without, as is does on my production server. So my .htaccess on my local testing environment, went like this:

BROKEN: 
Redirect 301 /mypage /directory1/sub-directory/mypage/

FIXED:
Redirect 301 http://mydomain.com/mypage http://mydomain.com/directory1/sub-directory/mypage/

Comment: @user675891 thank you for your response, but I need to be able to use the same .htaccess file on my development and testing environment, so rewriting urls to full is not a feature :)  `RewriteRule ^/page1.html$ /dir1/page.html [R=301,L]` resolved issue

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, for me this didn't work as well:

```
RewriteRule ^/page1.html$ /dir1/page.html [R=301,L]
```

What worked for me is to **remove** the leading slash, and add soft tailing slash with ?, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(page1.html)/?$ dir1/page.html [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, it's working as expected.

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  Redirect 301 /our_clients/nike /project/nike-nofyme-campaigns
 </IfModule>
```