# 301 Redirect in .htacess file produces 500 error page

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am trying to get my 301 redirects in Wordpress to work. I have done this with out any issues on a previous Wordpress site. Here is what I have current that is producing the 500 error page when I check the main website not just the redirect.

Thanks for the help!

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Redirect 301 /images/kids%20menu.pdf http://ww2.landonwinery.com/bistro/bistro-kids-menu/
Redirect 301 /images/landon%20dinner.pdf http://ww2.landonwinery.com/bistro/bistro-dinner-menu/
Redirect 301 /images/landon%20dinner%202014.pdf http://ww2.landonwinery.com/bistro/bistro-dinner-menu/
Redirect 301 /images/landon%20lunch%202014.pdf http://ww2.landonwinery.com/bistro/bistro-lunch-menu/
```

Comment: Try moving the Redirect 301 to just below the rewriteBase line.

Comment: I tried that and it still gives me the 500 error for the whole site

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the whole `Rediret 301` rules to

```
RewriteRule ^/thefile.html$ /yourdirectory/thefile.html [R=301,L]
```

Have  a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323557/redirect-301-in-htaccess-causes-500-server-error-redirect-to-non-url) for the further checkout..

Comment: Not sure if I need to edit what you gave me or just paste it in. I am not very familiar with htacess editing. This is what I have in my file. (this includes some other plugin information too and ALL The redirects) http://ww2.landonwinery.com/wp-content/Redirects%202.txt