# Apache .htaccess "Redirect to non-url" error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've not used URL rewriting on .htaccess for a while, and now I think I've forgot some of the basis.
This is my server directory structure:

```
https://www.domain.com/dir/
```

In which I've put my website, with those files:

```
index.php
list.php
edit.php
home.php
```

What I wanted to achieve is this: User writes url like `https://www.domain.com/list` and `.htaccess` sends that request to `index.php?section=list`.

So, this is my current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir

Redirect on HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteRule /([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /index.php?section=$1 [NC,L]
```

Testing it on [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) seems to work as expected, but not on my webserver.
I've got no more `.htaccess` files in the server root dir, and by viewing server logs I only get `Redirect to non-URL` errors.
I've also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323557/redirect-301-in-htaccess-causes-500-server-error-redirect-to-non-url) but it didn't help me so far.

Comment: Does your server have mod_rewrite switched on? (And you are using a linux server, right?)

Comment: Yes, it's a Linux server. Wait a second, should i search for `mod_rewrite` in `phpinfo()` right? If yes... I'm so dumb this morning...

Comment: What is current your working URL `http://domain.com/index.php?section=list` OR `http://domain.com/dir/index.php?section=list` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this .htaccess in `/dir/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will support pretty URL as `http://domain.com/dir/list`

Comment: Thank you. I think that I'm missing something. `http://www.domain.com/dir/list` is not working. It shows 404 Error `index.php` was not found

Comment: Ah sorry, try it now. I had `/` before `index.php`

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please briefly explain me what was wrong? Just to avoid same errors (:

Comment: Yes sure. You had `/` before `index.php` which was routing to `index.php` in the parent directory of `/dir/`. Also your regex pattern was `/([a-zA-Z]+)/$` which expected a `/` before `list` but in htaccess leading slash from URI is stripped causing your pattern to fail the match.